# How to add Map<String,String> in Collection<Map<String,String>>

Tags: java, collections

I want to add `Map<String,String>` to a `Collection<Map<String,String>>` can anyone guide me how we can do this ?

Comment: With that `Collection`'s `add` method, like any other. What problem are you having, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is use `Collection.add()` like you would with any other collection item. There isn't anything truly different between adding a String to an ArrayList and adding a Map to another type of Collection. The thing that's probably throwing you off is the extra angle brackets (`<>`). However, you do need to choose a type of Collection to declare. You can't really just declare a `new Collection<>()`. I'd recommend either an ArrayList or a HashSet.

Either declare a map first then add it to the collection:

```java
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
Collection<Map<String, String>> collection = new HashSet<>();
collection.add(map);
```

Or just declare it once you want to add it:

```java
Collection<Map<String, String>> collection = new HashSet<>();
collection.add(new HashMap<>());
```

P.S. Don't forget to import everything:

```java
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
```